# aura:handler has invalid name attribute value:

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm going through the Salesforce Trailhead Module on Lightning Components and I'm on the section for [Handling Events with Client Side Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lightning_components/lightning_components_events_handle). I'm copying the Component Event example and when saving the component that is supposed to be handling an event I get the following error.

> Failed to save undefined: aura:handler has invalid name attribute value: trailheadMessage1: Source

This component is named "trailheadReceiver.cmp" and code is as follows

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="myText" type="String" default="None" />    
    <aura:handler name="trailheadMessage1" action="{!c.answer1}" />

    <c:trailheadSender />
    Message: {!v.myText}
</aura:component>
```

My event component is named "trailheadMessage1.evt" and the code is as follows:

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT" description="Event template" >
    <aura:attribute name="text1" type="String" />
</aura:event>
```

My component that is generating the event is named "trailheadSender.cmp" and the code is as follows:

```
<aura:component >    
    <aura:registerEvent name="trailheadMessage1" type="c:trailheadMessage1" />
    <ui:button label="1" press="{!c.send1}" />
    <ui:button label="2" press="{!c.send1}" />
</aura:component>
```

The name I'm using in my handler matches the name of the event component, as well as the name I've put in the  tag.  I've tried adding the event attribute to the  tag, but I get an error saying that it can only have the name of event attributes, but not both.  I've tried using the event attribute only, but then it complains that is only for APPLICATION events.

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error, or how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing:

`<c:trailheadSender />`

to

`<c:trailheadSender trailheadMessage1="{!c.answer1}" />`

and remove:

```
<aura:handler name="trailheadMessage1" action="{!c.answer1}" />
```

Comment: When I do that I get the following error "Failed to save undefined: A aura:handler that specifies an event="" attribute must handle an application event. Either change the aura:event to have type="APPLICATION" or alternately change the aura:handler to specify a name="" attribute.: Source"  It seems using the event attribute is only mean for application level events.

Comment: Updated the answer. You need to specify both the name and the event in the handler I think.

Comment: Sadly no luck, trying to add both the name and event attributes gives the following error: "Failed to save undefined: aura:handler must specify one and only one of name="…" or event="…": Source"

Comment: Interesting - the Trailhead example shows both specified.

Comment: Try the updated answer again please :)

Comment: Well, your updated answer allowed me to save the component (though I'm not exactly sure what is happening).  However when I try to run the app, and click the buttons I get this error "Uncaught error in $A.run() : component is not defined"

Comment: Marking your answer as correct.  My last error was due to a typo in my component controller.  Any chance you can explain what is happening?

Answer (score 4):

The Lightning Components module has been updated for Winter '16 in response to the Lightning Desktop launch. However, I believe you're still running a Summer '15 org. 
In receiver.cmp, you would have to replace the following lines:

```
<aura:handler name="messageEvent" event="c:theMessage" action="{!c.answer}"/>
<c:sender />
```

Replace those lines with:

```
<c:sender messageEvent="{!c.answer}"/>
```

This change corresponds to [Component Event Bubbling](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_lightning_event_bubbling.htm) in the Winter '16 release notes.

Comment: Indeed I am using a Summer '15 org, as I do not yet have access to a Winter '16 one.

Comment: Can you tell me where is this  `<c:sender messageEvent="{!c.answer}"/>` documented? I also run under same use case. My event is `Component` type  and i am using `<aura:handler event="c:theMessage"  name = 'messageEvent' action="{!c.answer}"/> `.  I am using this based on trail head module.

Comment: @Ankuli, you'll need `<c:sender messageEvent="{!c.answer}"/>` only if you're still on a Summer '15 org. Trailhead has been updated for Winter '16 so that line of code is no longer there.